# how to change raster order in r

Tags: r, raster

i have a trouble in making a raster stack

when i read the raster file (below is the code)

`clim_fut_26_2050 <- stack(list.files(path= paste('D:/hd26bi50/', sep=''), pattern='tif', full.names=TRUE ))`

**listfile result**

```
list.files(path= paste('D:/hd26bi50/', sep='')) = [1] "D:/hd26bi50/bio1.tif"  "D:/hd26bi50/bio10.tif" "D:/hd26bi50/bio11.tif" "D:/hd26bi50/bio12.tif" "D:/hd26bi50/bio13.tif"
 [6] "D:/hd26bi50/bio14.tif" "D:/hd26bi50/bio15.tif" "D:/hd26bi50/bio16.tif" "D:/hd26bi50/bio17.tif" "D:/hd26bi50/bio18.tif"
[11] "D:/hd26bi50/bio19.tif" "D:/hd26bi50/bio2.tif"  "D:/hd26bi50/bio3.tif"  "D:/hd26bi50/bio4.tif"  "D:/hd26bi50/bio5.tif" 
[16] "D:/hd26bi50/bio6.tif"  "D:/hd26bi50/bio7.tif"  "D:/hd26bi50/bio8.tif"  "D:/hd26bi50/bio9.tif"
```

the order of file is messy (not ordered)

```
 names(clim_fut_26_2050)
 [1] "bio1"  "bio10" "bio11" "bio12" "bio13" "bio14" "bio15" "bio16" "bio17" 
 "bio18" "bio19" "bio2"  "bio3"  "bio4"  "bio5"  "bio6"  "bio7" 
 [18] "bio8"  "bio9"
```

how to reorder this layers?

help me T.T

Answer (score 2):

The `mixedsort` function in `gtools` library can reorder the objects in the list:

```
library(gtools)
setwd('D:/hd26bi50')
s <- stack(mixedsort(list.files(pattern='tif', full.names=TRUE )))
```